# WebJob cannot be added from portal if deployment form source control is configured

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Today we experienced the following message in Azure Portal

> WebJob cannot be added from portal if deployment form source control is configured.

[image: Error Azure Portal]

We assume that this is a *new* feature hence the spelling is incorrect: 'deployment *form* source control' should be 'deployment *from* source control'.

I have no clue where to set a setting that solved this.

It has to be somewhere in DevOps we assume.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We solved it by **not** disconnecting a pipeline.

We solved it by implementing a seperate WebJob Build/Release Pipeline.

Here are the steps that worked for us:

**In Azure Portal**

- Create a virtual application in your app service
  [image]

**In DevOps**

- In your  build pipeline
  [image]
  **Important Notice:** add the following Argument: `--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` to the build step.
- In your release pipeline
  [image]

This deploys the WebJob to the correct directory. In our case: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ms-reporting-webjob-dev-CI/drop`

Having a look at the Kudo Console in our App Service the file location for our WebJob is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Added the answer flag.@LeoLiu-MSFT

Comment: when deploying, is it important to stop first the app service and then, the web jobs? or web jobs first and then web app service?

Answer (score 12):

#### Kudu Console

The workaround that worked for me was uploading the webjob directly via the Kudu Console.

Open the Kudu Console by selecting "Advanced Tool" --> "Go" in Your App Service on the Azure Portal.

Once on the Kudu portal open a "Debug Console" --> "CMD"

Go to the directory for your webjobs: "d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{job name}" (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs)

Then drag and drop the .zip file you prepared to upload your webjob (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)

The job will now be listed on the Azure Portal and be started.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following physical path in the Virtual Application and it solved it for us

> site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\jobname

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and noticed there was an old deployment pipeline connected to our web job in the Deployment Center blade.  Disconnecting this solved the problem for us and we were able to manually deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I used Kudu console to upload the webjobs

You can go to the path D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\ and then upload the webjob folder here and then this shows up in your Webjobs portal as well

Comment: To update the cron expression to schedule the webjob, please use/add Settings.job file in the respective webjob folder and then add the cron expression as below

{
 "schedule": "0 0/30 * * * *"
}

Above schedule runs for every 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the new CICD pipeline creation of this issue. Don't use chrome/safer while disconnecting the deployment center. Please use the latest IE or Microsoft Edge. it will allow the disconnect of the deployment center. I am able to do that in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, and there was default configuration in deployment center for my web application, but we are not deploying the code from reposiotry, so we disabled that option. We are deploying web application from visual studio.
[image]

Currently the image showing disabled repository options in deployment center of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because You set CI/CD for your web app deployment.

If you set your deployment with Azure Devops pipelines, and you are doing the yaml file approach, then maybe this is what you are looking for.

firstly you need to set the branch that you want to be triggred when a new commit has been pushed to it.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/staging

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'

pr: none # Disable pull request triggers.
```

To make our pipeline a little bit organized, We will work with **stages**, let's create our `Build` stage, here I am building a `.Net` app, you can replace the build task with the build you want.

```
stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'  #The agent that will be used to start this stage

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet build'
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: 'MySuperApp/BackgroundService.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

then I will run dotnet publish, that publishes the application and its dependencies to a folder for deployment to a hosting system.

and here comes the important part, when you create a webjob from azure portal, its files are stored under specific folder.

for Continuous webjobs, it will be stored under `\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Continuous`

and for Triggered webjobs it will be under `\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered`

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet publish'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/MySuperAppBGS'
        projects: 'MySuperApp/BackgroundService.csproj'
        publishWebProjects: false
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: false
```

for me I need to deploy a continuous webjob, as you can see in the `arguments` within `inputs:`

```
--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/MySuperAppBGS'
```

the dotnet publish will put the generated files under `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/MySuperAppBGS`

then I will zip the content of `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish_output/` which is `App_Data/jobs/continuous/MySuperAppBGS`

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Zip Published Files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MySuperAppAPIBackgroundService.zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
```

and publish the content of `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` to `drop` artifact, which our zip file exist `MySuperAppAPIBackgroundService.zip`, in order to use it, in the next stage

```
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Build artifacts'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Here is the second stage, that will deploy our zip file to the web app service, then it will be unzipped leaving
`App_Data/jobs/continuous/MySuperAppBGS/*` under `\site\wwwroot\`

```
- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy'
    environment: 'MySuperAppAPI_BackGround_Staging_env' #just an env variable, that will be used later if you want, give it whatever name you like
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy MySuperAppAPIBackgroundService.zip to MySuperAppAPI-Staging-BackgroundService'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Your Azure service connection'
              appType: 'webApp'
              appName: 'MySuperAppAPI-Staging-BackgroundService'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/MySuperAppAPIBackgroundService.zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

Note: in the second stage, I didn't call `DownloadBuildArtifacts@0` task, because I used `deploy:` within `- deployment:` job that auto inject the Download artifact task, and to access the published Artifact from the previous stage, you use `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` following by the artifact name you provided, in my case it is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop`

Hope I was clear, for any clarification don't hesitate to ask me.