# Start and Stop of continuous Azure webJob with Azure WebApp Rest API results in 404 Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I deployed a continuous WebJobs to my existing Azure WebApp using DevOps. It is up and running.

When I tried to stop the webJob in the Azure web frontend it did not work.
So I used the [stop Command of the Azure WebApp API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/stop).

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/continuouswebjobs/{webJobName}/stop?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Surprisingly this call returned a 404 error.

However, when I executed the [Get Continuous WebJob Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getcontinuouswebjob) it returns all infos about the webJob, which means that it could be found.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/continuouswebjobs/{webJobName}?api-version=2016-08-01
```

I also tried using the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job).

```
POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/stop
```

However, the stop command resulted in the same 404 response message whereas the get command resulted in a positive result that the WebJob is in State "Running".

```
GET /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}
```

Is there any reason for this behavior? How is it possible to start/ stop the webJob using the above mentioned post requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turned out the way I was deploying was the root of the problem.

Daniels answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975063/450711) helped me a lot.

Basically you need to create a Virtual Application within your WebApp and then deploy your WebJob to this application from within Azure Devops.

When done this way you are in a position to successfully start/ stop the continuous webjob with all of the above mentioned APIs.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I read here, the accepted answer's linked subject (worth reading!), and my own configuration problem that concerned only one project of our projects, I noticed that in our case, the webjob that causes the 404 error was not published with the same output directory, it was published with `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/My.Api/app_data/jobs/Continuous/MyWebjob` instead of `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/My.Api/app_data/jobs/Continuous/`

So in our case we don't use virtual applications.

Answer (score -1):

What's your way to stop webjob in the front end?

And the API to stop a continuous webjob, you could try with this

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/continuouswebjobs/{webJobName}/stop?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Further more information, you could refer to this doc:[Stop Continuous Web Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/stopcontinuouswebjob)

Comment: I also tried this command which resulted in the same 404 error; actually this is the exact link I posted in my question.
In the frontend I tried to stop the webJob pressing the "stop" button, which of course was my first attempt

Comment: If this doesn't work, pease try with this one.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job

Comment: If you use Get Continuous Web Job, what's you webjob status?

Comment: Status is "Running"

Comment: Could you stop it in azure portal and there is a powershell method to stop webjob.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/stop-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0