# How to run scheduled scripts using Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

I want to run a scheduled script using WebJob.
Due to source control enabled, I could not create WebJob using portal & had to copy files using Kudu (Diagnostic) Console. These are the files under triggered jobs in the folder:

[image]

The run.js file simply calls an API. The settings.job contains the schedule I want it to run at:
{
"schedule": "0 /1 * * * *"
}
But the job does not start on its own or shows up in list of WebJobs:
[image]

Is there something else that needs to be done to publish or trigger a WebJob or something more that I need to add to settings.job file?
I have been referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972072/webjob-cannot-be-added-from-portal-if-deployment-form-source-control-is-configur)

Comment: What is the path to the files in the screenshot?

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow my steps, you can solve the problems you can't add webjob on portal.**

> Due to source control enabled, I could not create WebJob using portal & had to copy files using Kudu (Diagnostic) Console.

Step 1. Add a webjob arbitrarily on the portal.（upload `.zip` file or create by kudu）

[image]

[image]

[image]

Step 2. Deploy by  VS2019(source control)

[image]

Step 3. After success, you  will find you can add webjob by upload `.zip` file.

[image]

Now, I will upload nodejs webjob.

***Please note that you need to create a continuous or Triggered webjob. The two are different. In the portal, the schedule of the continuous webjob is displayed as n/a, while the Triggered display format is such as: `0 */15 * * * *`.***

1. run program in my local pc and it works fine.

[image]

2. Compress it and upload in portal.

[image]

3. check running logs and it works fine, and result is same as local.

[image]

Finally ,let us check the content in .zip file.

[image]