# How do I add a webjob to my aspnet appservice using only the CLI

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am working on macOS with an external text editor (NOT VisualStudio).
I have an asp.net project that I push to my app service using

`git push azure main:master`
the remote is configured as such `https://$name:pass@name.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/name.git`

when I go to the web jobs section in the app service to add a web job, I get the error message:

[image]

I want to continue using my source control push method while developing...
however I would also like to add a csharp console webjob .
I have followed the tutorial here (A) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started, and have a functoining console app that consumes a message from a queue.

How can I push this extra console app to my Kudu instance?
I read here that there is a 'hidden' structure not in the main doucmentation (A) I linked above for the tutorial: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs.

Do I have to manually zip the result of `dotnet publish -c Release` to some Kudu folder? Or is there a more elegant way by somehow including this project inside my git repo that I push normally... or using an `az cli` tool to push the webjob to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to push directly using az cli

```
 az webapp deploy --name $APP_NAME -g $RG \
                  --src-path program.py \
                  --type static \
                  --target-path /home/site/Jobs/continuous/Job$RANDOM/program.py
```

for larger programs in .net I just dumped the project on Kudu, unzipped, and rebuilt  (I'm on a mac m1 so can't build against x64 without some hoops, this was easier workaround)

```
 # on my machine
 az webapp deploy --name $APP_NAME -g $RG \
                  --src-path path_to_dotnet_project.zip \
                  --type static \
                  --target-path /home/site/Jobs/continuous/Job5/myproject.zip
```

then on the app service (using kudu cmd/powershell)

```
cd /home/site/Jobs/continuous/Job5
unzip myproject.zip
dotnet build -c Release
cp bin/release/net6.0/* /home/site/Jobs/continuous/MyNewJob
#job in MyNewJob automatically starts since this is in the 'continuous' folder
```

Answer (score 0):

- I created the Web Job and tried to Add it from App service, got the below error.
  [image]
- Using Azure CLI, we can deploy our Web Jobs to App Service
- Web Jobs need to be deployed to the below folder in KUDU Console, Create a folder with Web Job Name in the below path

```cs
app_data\jobs\triggered\NewFolder
```

- Zip all the contents of the Web Job into one folder.
- `wwwroot` folder path will be read-only mode, we need to enable it by setting **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** to 1
- Set the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to 1 in WebApp => Configuration => Application Settings or run the CLI command to set it.

```cs
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group YourRGName --name AppServiceName --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"
```

- Zip deploy Web Job to the existing Azure App service

```cs
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group YourRGName --name YourAppService --src YourZipFilePath
```

- We can directly drag and drop the Web Jobs Zip folder from the KUDU Console as well

[image]

[image]

- We can deploy our Web Jobs in many ways.
  We can FTP / Use Build Pipelines/ Zip Deploy.

Comment: Also refer this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972072/webjob-cannot-be-added-from-portal-if-deployment-form-source-control-is-configur)